# Preg Match Help - Find content between tag with unknown classes

Tags: php, preg-match

I know this is possible, but for the life of me I can not work it out.

Consider this scenario:

```
$html = '<tr>
    <td>Some Marker I know<td>
    <td>This is what I want</td>
<tr>
```

So a preg_match would be something like:

```
preg_match_all( '#Some Marker I know<td><td>(.*?)</td>#', $html, $match );
```

However I can't be sure of certain things, and thus need somethign which allows more flexiability

Example:

```
$html = '<tr class='unknown another' id='no idea'>
    <td attribute='no idea' class='no idea'>Some Marker I know<td>
    <label>This is what I want</label>
<tr>
```

Notice I have changed the:
- Classes and ID - which may or may not exist
- The html tags - which might not be TDs (might be a DIV) but will always be the next one.

So to be clear what im looking to get is the string 'This is what I want'

In english the search term would be something along the lines of:

- Get me the contents of the next tag/element
- Where the content of the previous element is 'Some Marker I know
- But where the tags inbetween might (or might not) have classes, IDs and so on

I know this isnt the easiest things to example, but I was pretty sure you could use wildcards in this to help it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what output you want. Is it the content of the next element after the one which has the value `Some Marker I know`, regardless of the type of element? Could you please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi Nick - Ive editted it, hope that helps.

Comment: Don't do it!  You'll unleash a non-euclidean horror!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way to process HTML in PHP is using the [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class. Once you've read your HTML into a DomDocument, you can then use [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search. In this case, we want to search for the element after the one which has the text value `Some Marker I know`. The XPath for that is

```
//*[text()="Some Marker I know"]/following-sibling::*
```

We can use that in PHP like so:

```
$html = "<tr class='unknown another' id='no idea'>
    <td attribute='no idea' class='no idea'>Some Marker I know<td>
    <label>This is what I want</label>
<tr>";
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$marker = $xpath->query('//*[text()="Some Marker I know"]/following-sibling::*');
echo(trim($marker[0]->nodeValue));
```

Output:

```
This is what I want
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JBHI6)